# How to force numeric input keypad on listview's search filter bar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm developing a mobile web app using jQuery Mobile.

For the general form's input fields we can use `<input type="tel" />` or `<input type="number" />`, what about on the search filter bar of some particular listview which are need to be only numeric input.

What is the jQuery script for control of what type of keyboard to appear?

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't one. That's under the browser's/OS's control. All you can do is specify a certain `input type` and hope the browser will play along.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972577/change-listview-search-field-input-type

Answer (score 1):

iOS will automatically infer what type of keyboard to display based on the 'type' attribute of your input element.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html